# AutomationProperties.HelpText doesn't work on UWP ListView

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a ListView like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="ArtistsList"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ArtistsCVS}}"
          SelectionMode="None"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewContainerStrecher}"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          ItemClick="ArtistsList_ItemClick">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:DAPP">
            <Grid AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding artist}"
                  AutomationProperties.HelpText="Navigate to artist info page.">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Grid.Column="0"
                       MaxWidth="60"
                       Source="{Binding thumb}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                <Grid Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding artist}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

When I try to use Narrator it reads the Artist name but it doesn't read help text. Also, I want to know if is it possible to bind two values a AutomationProperties.Name?

For example, I have an ArtistName and a SongName then for example use `AutomationProperties.Name = "{Binding ArtistName};{Binding songName}"` then it reads something like Artist (little pause) SongName.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I try to use Narrator it reads the Artist name but it doesn't read help text.

Setting [AutomationProperties.HelpText attached property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.automation.automationproperties.helptext) inside `DataTemplate` won't work here. To solve this issue, we can using a custom [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242878)  and overriding [PrepareContainerForItemOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242840) method to set automation properties. And this is also the recommended way for adding accessibility support to the items in a `ListView`.

For example:

```cs
public class MyList : ListView
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        FrameworkElement source = element as FrameworkElement;

        source.SetBinding(AutomationProperties.NameProperty, new Binding
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("Content.artist"),
            RelativeSource = new RelativeSource() { Mode = RelativeSourceMode.Self }
        });

        AutomationProperties.SetHelpText(source, "Navigate to artist info page.");
    }
}
```

Then you can use `MyList` instead of `ListView` and there is no need to set `AutomationProperties.Name` and `AutomationProperties.HelpText` in `Grid` any more. For more info, please see [XAML accessibility sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-accessibility-sample-d63e820d).

> I want to know is it possible to bind two values a AutomationProperties.Name?

UWP has no multibinding support out of the box. But if the `ArtistName` and `songName` come form one model or view model, then we can use a Converter to achieve this like:

```cs
public class AutomationPropertiesConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        //Suppose ArtistName and songName are the properties of Song class
        var song = (Song)value;

        return $"{song?.ArtistName} - {song?.songName}";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And use the Converter like:

```cs
public class MyList : ListView
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        FrameworkElement source = element as FrameworkElement;

        //Suppose Song class is the DataType of the DataTemplate
        source.SetBinding(AutomationProperties.NameProperty, new Binding
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("Content"),
            RelativeSource = new RelativeSource() { Mode = RelativeSourceMode.Self },
            Converter = new AutomationPropertiesConverter()
        });

        AutomationProperties.SetHelpText(source, "Navigate to artist info page.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much . I used the Converter you provided here, I works perfectly :)